# google sheets 504 error "Deadline expired before operation could complete"

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I've been using the same `google-api-python-client` to interact with gsheets. All of a sudden getting the following error:

`HttpError: <HttpError 504 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1DPGOfVqnJANZRt3lC3C6XBvgnuLO4oqfn3i5AmsdfMM/values/Data%21A10%3AAM?alt=json returned "Deadline expired before operation could complete."`

on this line of code 
`result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=key, range=ranges).execute()`

where `self.service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,                           discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)` ... quickstart code taken from Google's example. Was working fine until today. I haven't ran the code in a week.